# Fortran double precision converted to Python float

Tags: python, numpy, fortran90, gfortran, f2py

I have the following subroutine in `generation.f90`

```
SUBROUTINE generation(t, prob)
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: t
    REAL(8), INTENT(OUT) :: prob
    INTEGER :: nT2, c

    Do some stuff with t, nT2 and c

    prob = nT2/(DBLE(1.0)*c)
END SUBROUTINE generation
```

I want to use it in Python, so I wrap it with `f2py`

`f2py -c -m generation generation.f90 --fcompiler=gnu95`

Then in `ipython` I do

```
from generation import *
a = generation(10000); type(a)
```

and I get `float`. I checked the C file `testmodule.c` generated with

`f2py generation.f90 -m test`

and `prob` is type `double`. I would like `type(a)` to be `numpy.float64`. What should I do? I am fairly new to Fortran and f2py.

Comment: real(8)  is not guaranteed to give you double precision BTW

Comment: im not familiar with f2py, but why does a *subroutine* return *anything*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats in python are double precision by default. The harder problem is to get a single-precision float, which requires numpy or some other mathematics package. But in your case, you shouldn't have any concerns.

Comment: I see. My problem was actually the default print format of Python.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer mentions, Python's `float` is already a double-precision number.

However, if you want to convert it, you can use

```
import numpy as np
a = np.float64(a)
```

See the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) for details on conversions.

Comment: Since I can't select two answers, I chose the first posted.