# SciPy interpolation: precision of methods?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

[SciPy interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html) has 3 supported methods:

> Supported are “linear” and “nearest”, and “**splinef2d**”. “splinef2d” is only supported for 2-dimensional data.

In [Wikiversity](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cubic_Spline_Interpolation), it is explained as a polynomial interpolation, and I think should be more precise than linear...

So 2 questions here:

1. what is splinef2d? It is the one of wikiversity link?
2. Which one of 3 avalaible methods is more precise in interpolation? nearest ,bilinear or splinef2d?

Comment: Your first link is to a specific method provided by a specific module; it's not a general Python concept. One of the arguments to that method can take the values `"linear"`, `"nearest"`, or `"splinef2d"`.

Comment: Is the current method I'm using. So I'm interested in fully understand methods, particularly precision.

Comment: "Precision" is something that only applies to the method you are calling. Or are you asking about the different interpolation techniques themselves, which has nothing to do with Python?

Comment: The different interpolation techniques. I don't find in Python documentation which one is "splinef2d" exactly (Q1 in the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a bit more digging in `scipy`. The `splinef2d` method is essentially fitting your data to a surface. The method you need to explore further is [scipy.interpolate.bisplrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep). This wraps around FITPACK's [surffit](http://www.netlib.org/dierckx/surfit.f) subroutine. As far as I can tell the variables are of type `real`. With default compiler settings this means its `real(kind=8)` thus you are looking at `double` precision.This is expected to be contagious thus, python also deals with the same precision.

You can repeat the exercise now for [QHull](http://www.qhull.org) for details on LinearND interpolation. Based on what I see from their git repo, it seems to be of `double` precision.

On python's side, the variables are declared `float` and documentation says:

> On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision
>   available for a Python float

About the precision of wrapped functions, by default python's `float` has double precision. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23075366/4782513).